# password_verify неправильно работает

Tags: php

Перелопатил кучу материала и других вопросов, но ответа так и не нашел.
Есть вот такой вот код

```
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];
    $query = "SELECT login, password FROM admin WHERE login = '$login'";
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));

    if (!isset($user['login'])) {
        echo "Неверный логин или пароль";
    } elseif (!password_verify($pw, $user['password'])) {
        echo "Неверный логин или пароль";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['login'] = $res->login;
        $_SESSION['active'] = true;
        header('Location: admin.php');
    }
```

`password_verify()` выдает постоянно `false`, хотя хеши должны совпадать. В базе выделено под пароль 255 символов, т.е. хеш не режется.
Вот `var_dump` хеша из базы:

```
string(60) "$2y$10$BsXWs/HpUriavdHJRJgEpeJbCnZgXi1rIBaVr7jiTuyr8zNSrgZr6"
```

При этом в другом проекте все работает.

Comment: Должны и совпадают - это разные вещи) сделайте `var_dump(password_hash($pw))`, только `password_hash` - должен быть с теми же настройками, что и при регистрации. После этого сравнивайте по символам.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев я может чего-то не понимаю, но хеши ведь всегда будут разные. Они сравниваются не по буквам, иначе я бы даже не запаривался с `password_verify`, а просто проверял через `==`.

Comment: Простите, забыл про `salt`.